# "range.getNodes is not a function" when dom is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, range

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/cLkau8e9/5/ i'm trying to get all nodes in a range, but the function .getNodes() return an error, how?

```
<b id="bold">
   hi
</b>
<div id="root">
    <span>
        hello
    </span>
    <i>
     John
    </i>
</div>
```

JS

```
var root_node = document.getElementById("root");

//I must use this function
$( "#root" ).append( $( "#bold" ) );

var bold_node = document.getElementById("bold");

var range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(root_node.firstChild, root_node.firstChild.startOffset);
range.setEnd(bold_node, bold_node.endOffset); 

//error "range.getNodes is not a function", why?
var nodes = range.getNodes([3]);
```

Comment: According to the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), `Range` objects do not have a `getNodes()` method. Did something give you the impression that they do? What are you trying to do? What is that `[3]` for?

Comment: That method belongs to [`Rangy`](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangyRange#getNodes([Array_nodeTypes[,_Function_filter]])) library.

Comment: var nodes = range.cloneContents().querySelectorAll("*"); is a possible workaround to receive nodes

Comment: @axel.michel why http://jsfiddle.net/cLkau8e9/6/ with `var nodes = range.cloneContents().querySelectorAll("*");` nodes[0].nodeType is 1 and not 3?

Comment: @user3411039 Yes it is a SPAN-element? So why should it be 3 - text?

Comment: @axel.michel why in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cLkau8e9/7/ the third node is empty after range.cloneContents().querySelectorAll("*")? (the third node is `<b id="bold"> hi</b>`)

Comment: @user3411039 well not after cloneContents it is empty, it depends on how you select: http://jsfiddle.net/cLkau8e9/8/ shows a way to retrieve the text. It would be easier if you modify your question and explain your goal precisely. Since the very first comment here was the correct answer - there is no getNodes for a range, if you are looking for that, use the lib mentioned by Vohuman.